# TFS 2010 Email Alerts - Filter by more than one Status Code?

Tags: tfs-alerts

I am setting up my email alerts in TFS 2010 using the Alerts Explorer from the TFS Power Tools.

I want to receive an email when a build either fails or partially succeeds.  The filter seems to be too basic to achieve this.

I have created the filter as follows

> "TeamProject" = 'My Project' AND "StatusCode" = 'Failed' OR "StatusCode" = 'PartiallySucceeded'

but obviously this sends me an email whenever any project's build partially succeeds.  The filter I actually want is

> "TeamProject" = 'My Project' AND ("StatusCode" = 'Failed' OR "StatusCode" = 'PartiallySucceeded')

Is there a way to achieve this?  Can I input the value in such a way so it reads IN ('this' or 'that')?

I don't really want to have to create separate email rules for each status I'm interested in if I can help it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I finally found the solution.

On the alert definition tab select two or more rows and the buttons just above the table light up.  One of these is "Group selected clauses" and will create a sub clause with the results I was after.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

(This is based on the VS 2008 editor from the TFS 2008 Power Toys)

In the Alert Definition tab I don't think you can, but the Filter Expression tab gives more freedom, with AND and OR, as well as parentheses being supported.

Comment: Strangely the Filter Expression tab lets you type into it but any changes don't save.